# Understanding and interpreting the weighting parameter's scale in regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, interpretation, ridge-regression, weighted-data

Below is an equation for a least squares predicted value:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n X_{ij}\beta_j=y_i\space\space \text{for}\space\space j={1...m}$$
$\beta$ is the parameter we seek to minimize for least squares, and my regression is along 3 dimensions, therefore $m=3$.

In my work if I observe the minimum values of $\beta_1\approx.75,\space\beta_2\approx-1.2\space\beta_3\approx-8.9$

**My question is**: What can we infer about the train data in this feature if our minimum weight for $\beta_3$ is *significantly less than* than the other parameters?

Below are my conclusions.  But please let me know if you disagree with my interpretation:

1) There exists a high degree of variability in the data in this dimension. Without penalizing our parameter $\beta$ with a ridge parameter, the value of $\beta$ is very sensitive to these outliers.

2) Because the value of $\beta$ is very negative, the predicted output is over predicting the actual. (Is this a reasonable conclusion?)

3) (Geometrically speaking)This third dimension has the largest affect on our regression plane because the squared difference error represents the magnitude of the vector between predicted and actual. In this case, that magnitude (squared) is very large relative to the other dimensions. Therefore our plane's shape will be mostly be due to this dimension.

Update: All data is i.i.d.

Comment: If I understand well, you have standardized the predictor values?

Comment: That's correct. All of the data is standardized & preprocessed before the computation. I think my faultiest conclusion is #2, but feel confident in #1 and #3.

Comment: #3 Seems like a fair statement, I don't really understand what you mean by #1, if you are talking about variability, then reporting SE seems appropriate (?). I wouldn't conclude #2.

Comment: For your top formula, do you mean $\sum_{j=0}^m X_{ij}\beta_j=\hat{y}_i$? I don't understand the current formula you have written.

Comment: Hi Matt, not quite. $i$ represents the rows in matrix $X$. Each row represents one individual outcome. $j$ represents a feature of the outcome. So the data has $m$ columns. Therefore it is $m$ dimensional. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Your formula $\sum_{i=0}^n X_{ij}\beta_j=y_i\space\space \text{for}\space\space j={1...m}$ does not make sense. I'm assuming it's a simple typo and you mean to sum over $j$. If not, then I have no clue what you're saying.